# Link to random page where content present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller

I am using Rails 4.

I have two resources: `articles` and `subarticles`. `subarticles` are nested into `articles`.

I currently have a random button which takes the user to a random article. However, I would like it to only take them to an article page in which the `subarticle` is present.

What is the best way to go about this? I'm having trouble finding documentation.

Here is my random method in the articles_controller:

```
@items = Article.all
@randitem = @items[rand(@items.count)]
```

and in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Random Page", article_path(@randitem) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup a `counter_cache`? If not, I would recommend you to do so as it will allow you to do what you want in a more elegant way (with less code and less database query as well) :  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The article table needs then to have a `subarticles_count` field
  has_many :subarticles
end
class Subarticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then in your controller, you can query the `articles` that have `subarticles` :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Article.includes(:subarticles).where('subarticles_count > 0')
    @randitem = @items[rand(@items.count)]
  end
end
```

By the way, it's cleaner to use the Ruby `sample` method to get a random item from a collection :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Article.includes(:subarticles).where('subarticles_count > 0')
    @randitem = @items.sample
  end
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I set up the counter cache, but am getting this error. `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: subarticles_count: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (subarticles_count > 0)`

Comment: Did you create a migration in order to have the field `subarticles_count ` ?

Comment: I am getting close. What would i use in the view? I get this error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` when I try using my current link_to

Comment: mmm...that's weird. Is `@randitem` defined and has an id? Also, please update your post with some new code snippets so maybe I can see if there is any bug

Comment: Finally got it working. Had to default the count to zero and then update it with the correct count in the migration. Thank you again.